# panel box work on local host but not on github

Tags: html, github, sliders

So I have created this project for my Show and for some reason I created a panel box that works fine on my local host but not after I hosted it on Github. 
Here is my source-code:

```
        <!-- press -->
<div class="container">

    <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="section-press">
            <h2>Press <small>What the press said about NO SHOW</small></h2>
        </div> <!-- end page-header -->


        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-qa">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#qa-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-qa"><h3> The Advocate </h> </a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="qa-1">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="http://www.theadvocate.com/baton_rouge/entertainment_life/article_9d97eca2-39be-11e7-825b-bb7960e93753.html"><img border="0" alt="The Advocate" src="images/advocate.png" width="900px" height="auto"></a>
                    </div> <!-- end panel-body -->
                </div> <!-- end collapse -->
            </div> <!-- end panel -->

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#qa-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-qa"><h3> 225 Magazine </h></a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="qa-2">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="https://www.225batonrouge.com/things-to-do/nearly-year-series-no-show-comedy-team-keeps-jokes-fresh"><img border="0" alt="225" src="images/225.png" width="900px" height="auto"></a>
                    </div> <!-- end panel-body -->
                </div> <!-- end collapse -->
            </div> <!-- end panel -->

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#qa-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-qa"><h3>The Daily Reveille </h></a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="qa-3">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="http://www.lsunow.com/daily/students-headline-monthly-comedy-show/article_7d064d18-796f-11e6-89d8-27174a75f464.html"><img border="0" alt="The Reveille" src="images/lsu.png" width="900px" height="auto"></a>
                    </div> <!-- end panel-body -->
                </div> <!-- end collapse -->
            </div> <!-- end panel -->
        </div> <!-- end panel-group -->
    </section>

</div>

<!-- end press -->
```

This is what the panel box looks like:

[image]

It looks great, link is working, however all the button are non-responsive; which is weird because everything works fine on my computer. This also happens to my sliders with galleries of our show.

Here is the direct link to the page:

https://namburger.github.io/NOSHOWComedy/index.html#qa-2

So sorry, I'm quite new to web development so any help or even additional tips non-related to this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried your site and the panel works in Chrome, are you using FF to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the console and got this error in FF:

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   “http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js”

And you mentioned that it works great in localhost. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default) where you can read further

> Note: Since Firefox 55, the loading of mixed content is allowed on
>   localhost (see bug 903966).

I checked your headers and you're missing `s` in `http`:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Just change that to this:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So I changed it to what you suggested and it works fine now. Google calendar doesn't work on firefox though, but that should be an easy fix. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help :)